# How to display array values in a table: C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to learning C# and am trying to display array values in a table and be able to add to that array so that new items can be added to the table via textboxes. I've tried various different ways and everyone online seems to suggest databases or lists but I just want to be able to have an array and display its content in a table. It's for an inventory system if that helps.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, webpage with ASP.NET? What are you displaying this in?

Comment: WinForms - it's a .cs extension.

Comment: for this purpose, a list is way more appropriate than an array

Comment: Well a DataGridView would be easiest for getting a table view.

Comment: @Erik How would I display array values in the table though?

Comment: Im not sure but there should be a DataGridView.Items.Add() function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a few options.  You could add you array to a datatable (example), or add your array to a label.

You can try calling this after InitializeComponent();

```
void FillData()
{

        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
}
```

But, that only works if you have a dataGridView and a DataTable.

Comment: It's for my course - we haven't been taught lists yet and therefore the task is displaying the array values in a table. Sorry if that's a bit confusing.

Comment: Are you sure you want to display this with WinForms?  That's for web stuff, which a course would generally teach after you learn about a Lists.

Comment: Well, in Visual Studio when creating a new project we select "Windows Form Application" under Visual C#.